# how to view a doc from command line?

Tags: command-line, doc

As I mentioned there , how can I view documents( ex: .doc,.docx and all other formats ) from the command line ? Is there any way ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a terminal, not a word processor! So basically, it's not possible.

Comment: Do you want to see the doc formatted with different fonts and so on, or just have the text content dumped to the screen?

Comment: @FreudianSlip any , just want to view it with out any much modifications to the content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been using the following setup in several scripts (especially with version control):

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv odt2txt     # installs both tools
doc2odt test.doc                         # creates test.odt
odt2txt test.odt                         # displays the contents in the terminal
```

or for a docx file:

```
docx2txt test.docx                       # converts docx file
less test.txt                            # read the contents
```

Works like a charm and you can read your doc files in the terminal. This method is more complex than `catdoc` but it has the advantage that entries from a bibliographic management system are not displayed in their raw form.

For a LaTex file you can just your favorite terminal text editor to open and read it.

Comment: Hey , thanks for looking my post. could you explain this little bit " the advantage that entries from a bibliographic management system are not displayed in their raw form"

Comment: For academic writing people might use things like Mendeley, Endnote, JabRef to manage their citation references . With catdoc these appear as `[ADDIN: {author: Don Joey} { title: ...} ...]`. When you have many of them that is hard to read. This is where odt2txt conversion comes in handy because you will just see `Don Joey, Some Supposedly Interesting Book,...` rather than the raw info.

Comment: Ok Now I understood but I think the support of LaTex is missing here right ? catdoc can do that.

Comment: For LaTex you can just use vim. After all that's the goal of LaTex, to type text as is and convert it to publishable text afterwards.

Comment: No I mean to say that , If DOC consists of some symbolic things then Latex support we need to view them best . so is this can provide ? becasue Catdoc can provide that

Comment: Symbols you mean? I'd have to check how symbols are transposed in the conversion to a txt file. I think there must be quite some consistency. If you have a document, please try and let us know. The unoconv toolbelt is very advanced.

Comment: Yeah I will do that , thanks again for stopping by.

Answer (score 5):

To View word documents from the command line I found one named as catdoc.

to install it `sudo apt-get install catdoc`

then

```
catdoc -t filename.doc
```

You can specify the output format using the -a (text) or -t (LaTeX) option