# Tool for viewing LibreOffice Writer files in terminal window

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, text-editor

I am using a couple of documentation files in LibreOffice (`.odt`) format. Normally, I access them with LibreOffice Writer of course. But there are times when I can only connect to the site with a text terminal.

I am wondering if there is a terminal-based tool that can show me the contents of these files in approximate correct format? (The files mainly contain simple text, bullet lists, and a few 1x1 tables, so it's relatively simple stuff in terms of formatting.)

P.S. This question is not about starting LibreOffice itself from the command line (which is anwered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659741/how-to-open-a-file-with-libreoffice-writer-from-terminal)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to view a doc from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364872/how-to-view-a-doc-from-command-line)

Comment: Not in the original answer, but you can use `odt2txt document.odt | less` to directly view the file.

Comment: @RoVo That suits for an answer! It would be interesting whether `odt2txt` does a job as good as `libreoffice --convert-to` (which I'd expect to work *very* well without having tried it extensively). The latter (as far as I found out) is not able to write to stdout so that piping directly unfortunately isn't available for it. Caveat: If you just quickly want to view (or search!) the content of your document and maybe don't care too much about formatting, `odt2txt | …` is the way to go. Else let `libreoffice` convert your document as explained below.

Comment: Simple documents seem to be converted well with both tools. Unfortunately tables are not converted to ascii tables ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a tool called `odt2txt` that can convert `odt` to `txt`.

Compared to libreoffice I can see two benefits:

- Lightweight if you don't have libreoffice installed (e.g. on a server)
- It can print to stdout for direct viewing of files.

Installation:

```
sudo apt install odt2txt
```

Then you can directly view an `odt`:

```
odt2txt document.odt | less
```

Comment: If you want to convert to a file just redirect the output with `odt2txt document.odt > file` or use the `--output=file` option.

Answer (score 23):

`libreoffice` provides a `--convert-to` option which can be used to convert a document to e.g. text or html:

- convert `input.odt` to `input.txt`:
  `libreoffice --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" input.odt`
- convert every `.odt` in the current directory to `.html`:
  `libreoffice --convert-to "html:XHTML Writer File:UTF8" *.odt`
- convert every `.ods` in the current directory to `.csv`:
  `libreoffice --convert-to csv *.ods`

The output can be opened with the pager or terminal browser of your liking: `less`, `most` or `w3m` to list just three.

Comment: Nice! Can you use this to display the txt version directly in terminal instead of writing to a file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, see [my comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975937/tool-for-viewing-libreoffice-writer-files-in-terminal-window/975947?noredirect=1#comment1566018_975937).

Answer (score 12):

LibreOffice has a `--cat` option which exists in version 5.1 but not 4.2.  Not sure exactly when it was introduced.

```
libreoffice --cat "Untitled 1.odt" --headless | less
```

For more information:

```
libreoffice --help
```

Comment: It's a shame this useful option is neither documented in `libreoffice`'s manpage nor on https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters, however at least `libreoffice -h` lists it.

Comment: @Ganton: Please add a comment instead of editing the answer. I tried your suggestion in version 7.5 but could not get it to work, so I did this instead: `--convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8"`. Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html.

Comment: Beware that `libreoffice --cat` [silently does nothing if any LibreOffice is already open](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/convert-to-command-line-parameter/840/10).

Comment: @JimK: I added the comment, it's very important as it saves a lot of headaches if (for example) a LibreOffice Writer is being executed (because nothing happens, no error message is seen). The comment is about `libreoffice --cat`, there are no problems using `--convert-to` (as you have seen). About "*I tried your suggestion in version 7.5*", I added a warning, not a suggestion, could you clarify about that?

Comment: @Ganton: `--cat` did not work using 7.5, and closing all LibreOffice processes first (your suggestion) did not fix the problem.

Comment: @JimK: I've tried it again with Libreoffice 7.5.4.2 under Kubuntu 23.04, and with Kubuntu 22.04 and its Libreoffice (in a virtual machine), and the same happened: `libreoffice --cat FILE.odt` worked if (for example) `ps aux | grep [l]ibre` showed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that you can use is [`unoconv`](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv) which can convert *"between any document format supported by LibreOffice/OpenOffice"*

```
unoconv -f txt my.odt
```